# how to create a non empty map consumer in spring cloud contract(with groovy)?

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

Im writing a **spring cloud contract** for a http request , with a json body which one of its field (lets call it **myMap**) should be a **non empty** map (string to string) . So the requester(aka **consumer**) have to have something like this :
"myMap": {"key": "val"}

Is it possible to enforce such  thing in the contract ?

here an example for an existing contract i wrote just to make sure of the context:

```
  package contracts


org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    description("""
        Represents a successful scenario of registering new host 

        given:
            hostProperties are valid
        then:
            we'll register the host
    """)
    request {
        method 'POST'
        urlPath value(consumer(~/\/api\/hosts\/[a-zA-Z0-90-9]+/), producer('/api/hosts/icsl7875'))
        body([
            timeStamp     : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(334)),
            hyperThreaded : $(consumer(regex('^(true|false)$')), producer(false)),
            virtualMachine: $(consumer(regex('^(true|false)$')), producer(false)),
            poolName      : $(consumer(regex('(.+)')), producer("dev_regression")),
            osImage       : $(consumer(regex('(.+)')), producer("osImage1")),
            cores         : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(2)),
            memory        : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(256)),
            osRelease     : $(consumer(regex('(.+)')), producer("osRelease1")),
            wsmVeriosn    : $(consumer(regex('(.+)')), producer("8.2.16")),
            cpuCount      : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(2445L)),
            cpuMhz        : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(22354L)),
            cpuMips       : $(consumer(anyNumber()), producer(256F))
        ])
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJsonUtf8())
        }
    }
    response {
        status 201
        body([
            groupId: $('067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00')
        ])
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FOR REQUEST
I think you can use the `stubMatcher` section. JSON Path in WireMock should be resolved only if an entry is present. So if you pass in the `stubMatcher` a proper json path and validate it `byEquality` then it should be ok.

FOR RESPONSE:
You can use the `testMatcher` section and delegate together with `byCommand` (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/#_dynamic_properties_in_matchers_sections) . In the method you'll have to verify that the entry is non empty. In the docs there's sth like this `jsonPath('$.duck', byCommand('assertThatValueIsANumber($it)'))` . You'll need to do sth similar but assert that the entry is non empty.